# How to connect to different type of database in .NET Core

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I found this site https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/09/net-core-data-access/ but if I can use one variable to holed the different connection? For example I have MySQL and SQLite. So I write `var connection = new SqliteConnection()` and `var connection = new MySqlConnection()` but I need this variable `connection` as argument for functions. Can I somehow make it? And `object` does not help :(

Comment: Use the Interface ``IDbConnection`` or the base class ``DbConnection``? (if it exists in .NET Core) so instead of the ``var``, write ``IDbConnection connection = new SqliteConnection();``

Comment: why cant you use var and object as function parameter and compare the object type like `if(connection.GetType() == typeof(SqliteConnection))` and branch from there?

Comment: I am new in C# and when I try find information about universal connection I found nothing, that's why I've write here. Thanks guys for help :)

Comment: @Nju Just to let you know this is not something as simple as it looks. Making an db agnostic data layer is a difficult thing to do if you are not doing the most simple operations. EntityFramework still has difficulties supporting all the db types and nHibranate is buggy when you switch from one to the other. If you want agnostic data layer look in to repository pattern it's not perfect but is the most popular.

Comment: @FilipCordas Thanks but link for this repository would be nice if you may of course :)

Comment: @Nju Here is a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/advanced) It's on top of EF but you could implement your own IRepository. Note the generic filtering is difficult to implement with taw sql but you could use a none generic Repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `SqliteConnection` and `MySqlConnection` inherit from `DbConnection`  which you can use as parameter type. For even more abstraction: this type also implements `IDbConnection`